# How to draw a rectangle of random dimensions after you click something in Android using java?

Tags: java, android, xml

I have the onClick method already, so I know it goes in there but before I always used XML to draw something.  I don't know how to draw a rectangle onto the screen, and it should be in the java class not XML because you have to have random dimensions, so you use Math.random and XML has hard-coded values.

Comment: have you googled "draw shapes on the screen android development" or something? sounds like you haven't attempted anything yet.

Comment: Ya I have no idea how to go about doing this.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use the [ShapeDrawable](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#shape-drawable) object which will allow you to draw a shape as a View, which you can then add to your layout. You could also create a custom [view](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#on-view), and use the onDraw() method, which returns a Canvas, and drawRect() method.